# Numpy: Conditional sum rows using an mask array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have array a and array mask,

```
Array a:
[[1,1,2]
 [2,2,3]
 [3,5,2]
 [2,3,4]]

Array mask:
[[0,1]
 [1,1]
 [1,0]
 [0,0]]
```

How can I generate a array c with shape(2,3) in a numpy way like below:

```
Array c:
[[5, 3],
 [7, 3],
 [5, 5]])
```

where the 1st column is the sum of rows of array a indicated by mask[:,0] and 2nd column is the sum of rows indicated by mask[:,1], like below:

```
c[:0] = a[1]+a[2]

c[:1] = a[0]+a[1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `numpy` dot product, which is essentially a matrix product, as documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> For 2-D arrays it is the matrix product

```
import numpy as np
np.dot(a.transpose(), mask)

# array([[5, 3],
#        [7, 3],
#        [5, 5]])
```

Comment: Didn't think of doing a dot product. Thanks!